# mysql count where row = 0

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am trying to show a count but only where the column `deleted` is equal to 0

here is what i have tried

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where deleted=0")or die('Error ' );

$counter = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as personID FROM users");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $personID = $row['personID'];
    $personFname = $row['personFname'];
    $personSname = $row['personSname'] ;
    $llmail = $row['llmail'];
    $mainadmin = $row['mainadmin'];
     $delete = $row['delete'];
$num = mysql_fetch_array($counter);
$count1 = $num["personID"];
```

This shows a count of 4 however of the 4, 2 are deleted so it should only show 2 if this makes sense?

Comment: use PDO or mysqli..dont use mysql its deprecated in new versions of mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as personID FROM users WHERE deleted=0
```